# How to throw an error message with json_decode?

Tags: php, json

How can I throw an error message with `json_decode`?

For instance,

```
$error = array(
    "key_name" => "Keyname - empty!",
    "pub_name" => "Pubname - empty!",
    "path" => "path - empty!"
);

$json = json_encode($error);
$object = json_decode($json);
print_r($object->keyname);
```

I get,

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$key_namex in C:.... on line 32

`keyname` does not exist actually, so I wonder if I can check it with the `if condition`,

```
if(!$object->keyname) { .... }
```

is it possible?

and sometimes I there are no error content,

```
$error = array(
);

$json = json_encode($error);
$object = json_decode($json);
print_r($object->key_name);
```

so I thought of throwing an error before proceeding to the codes that follows,

```
if($object == '') {...}
```

is it possible?

Comment: It looks like your problem has nothing to do with `json_decode`. The title doesn't seem to fit your question at all.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. please change the title to the correct one if you like. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer to use [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)() over isset().

As opposed with isset(), property_exists() returns TRUE even if the property has the value NULL.

```
if( property_exists($object, 'keyname') ){ 
   throw new Exception( 'Object key does not exist.' ); //I prefer this method
   //or
   trigger_error( 'Object key does not exist.', E_USER_ERROR );
}
```

Incidentally, the same pattern should be used with arrays ([array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) is preferred over isset for that same reason).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to throw and catch json decode errors like this. You could extend this also to handle encode.

```
class Json {

   public static function decode($jsonString) {  
       if ((string)$jsonString !== $jsonString) {  // faster !is_string check
          throw new Exception('input should be a string');
       }

       $decodedString = json_decode($jsonString)

       if ((unset)$decodedString === $decodedString) { // faster is_null check, why NULL check because json_decode return NULL with failure. 
           $errorArray = error_get_last(); // fetch last error this should be the error of the json decode or it could be a date timezone error if you didn't set it correctly   

           throw new Exception($errorArray['message']); 
       }
       return $decodedString;
   }
}



try {
   Json::decode("ERROR");
} catch (Exception $e) {  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> keyname does not exist actually, so I wonder if I can check it with
>   the if condition,

You can, but with noo plain `if` but using `isset`:

```
if (isset($object->keyname)) { 

}
```

Just as you would for any variable / array offset.

As for checking if object has any properties, either use second argument to `json_decode` (to have associative array) or cast it to array and check if it is empty:

```
$obj = json_decode('{}');
if (!empty((array)$obj)) {
}
```